# Behavior of Screen-off of Android tablet vs Android Smartphone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

We are building a specific app for a business user. App logs GPS coordinates and post it to a service over HTTP.

While testing we found an issue that for the time tablet's(on Android 3.3) screen is switched off , app is not able to communicate with the external service. Moment I switch on the screen, app resumes instantly and then is able to communicate with external service.

I tested this on a smartphone(on Android 2.2) where it runs perfectly even when the phone screen is turned off.

I am not using any kind of service for my app. We started the development keeping smartphone in mind, but then took it to tablet too. We never imagined that tablet will behave differently.

Core concept of the app is to send GPS coordinates to a web service periodically.

Is there anything that I can do on the tablet that allows my app to run in background while screen is off or tablets are not built for this ?.

Comment: Does your tablet have a 3G connection? because most devices turn off their wifi connections while asleep

Comment: @JRaymond: yes it is 3g capable , but I am testing on WIFI. I didn't test this on data plan yet

Comment: @JRaymond: I just tested the Wifi Sleep policy on my tablet. Option that was already selected was : "Never(uses more battery power)"

Comment: Also note that some vendors suspend a lot of sensors when the device is in a low power state - I'm currently dealing with an issue where the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 suspends its accelerometers during sleep, and I can only imagine the same applies to location data.  The Motorola Xoom on the other hand, leaves them on.  Some vendors are more aggressive about battery life than others

Comment: @Jaymond : Problem is not  just about fetching GPS coordinates from the system while on sleep mode.

I tried testing my app on the samsung galaxy tablet using a simple timer based call to a webservice(I am simply sending constant values this time to the service). Even this doesn't get called when tablet is on sleep mode. On other hand , the smart phone  works perfectly fine. May be I need to see if there is any app on the smartphone that is using wake lock

Comment: So you're not presently holding a partial wake lock? I kind of assumed you were doing that already.  A partial wake lock would be necessary to maintain CPU activity during screen off

Comment: No I haven't done that. I don't have much exp in android. I am a .net developer and lately I've started doing some android work. I did read about wake lock somewhere , but I don't know yet if it's just a configuration thing or I've to change my code for implementing wake lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments above, it would appear that you need to acquire a Partial Wake Lock from the PowerManager.  Without a partial Wake lock, the normal behaviour for a device is to suspend the CPU while the screen is off.

Wake Locks are a bit of a tricky API, but the idea is that you aquire a lock at a specific level to prevent the device from going to sleep, either by keeping the screen on, keeping the screen on but dim, or just keeping the CPU on; then release it when you want to allow the device to sleep.  This will adversely affect your user's battery life, but by the sound of it the priority is on knowing device location.  [The Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) does a pretty good job of describing what's involved, and there are a [few tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/07/android-wakelock/) out there to get you started.